# Checked values display only on index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two many check box and i display the values on show file. All the values display which are checked and the check boxes which are not checked are blank display on my index file. I just want that the check box which are checked by user should display on the index file while remaining all the check box which are not checked should not shown with blank columns.Kindly guide me how i can do that. I am new in rails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, this should do the trick:

```
<% if @property.wheelchair_accessible %>
  <td>Wheelchair Accessible: </td><td><%= @property.wheelchair_accessible %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
<%="<td>Smooking Allowed: </td><td>#{@property.smooking_allowed}</td>" if @property.smooking_allowed %>
```

Comment: Just a little explanation about this for the OP: this does the same thing as my answer, but it uses inline if statement that can be provided after statement in Ruby, and String interpolation (#{..}) which includes variables value on that place. Only difference is in readability of the code.